# How to recursively traverse an XML File in Python?

Tags: python, xml

This is my XML File
**temp_student.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <studentinformation doc_version='2.0'>
  <student>
   <rollno>1</rollno>
   <name>ABC</name>
   <age>22</age>
   <gender>MALE</gender>
  </student>
    <student>
   <rollno>2</rollno>
   <name>DEF</name>
   <age>56</age>
   <gender>MALE</gender>
  </student>
 </studentinformation>
```

I'm trying to parse it using Element Tree. I've commented the section of the code to explain my problem

```
import subprocess,re,os,time,shutil,glob
import sys
from sys import stdout
from subprocess import STDOUT
from _winapi import NULL
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
from logging import root

xmlfile='temp_student.xml'
xml_tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
tree_root = xml_tree.getroot()
print('Root Tag is '+str(tree_root.tag))
print('Root Attrib is '+str(tree_root.attrib))
print('Printing the children from root ')
# 1 for child_root in tree_root:
#     for child_in in child_root:
         # perform some operation
# 2 for child_in in child_root in tree_root:
         # perform some operation
```

I thought of trying **#2**
by putting the entire statement in a single line but it fails because child_root is NOT defined

> File "getsccontent.py", line 47, in 
>           for child_in_child_root in child_root in tree_root:
>       NameError: name 'child_root' is not defined

Is there any simpler way than writing multiple nested for statements to traverse N  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single-line version but it's not simpler.

```
for child in [child for child_root in tree_root for child in child_root]:
    print(child)
```

I'd use #1 because there's no need for recursion in this case. Only when depth of the tree reaches 3 I'll write a recursive traversing method.

Comment: can you please explain the logic ? Is this a list comprehension ? If Yes, a brief explanation of how it works might be useful

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar This is list comprehension. A simpler example: [(x, y) for x in range(1, 5) for y in range(0, x)], where (x, y) is the output expression, for x in range(1, 5) and for y in range(0, x) are the two input expressions that defines the input list. Note that the second input expression can depend on the first expression.